# How can I read vb script and stored procedures from a legacy access 2003 database without windows?

Tags: ms-access-2003

I need to analyse an old application written in MS Access 2003 - the logic was written in a series of stored procedures with the execution of those stored procedures controlled by visual basic code. The stored procedures are the most inportant aspect for me to recover.

I only need to read the definitions, I don't need to run the application.

I do not have a windows PC - I'm on a mac and there is no version of ms access for a mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no stored procedures in Access. Do you mean action queries? -- Anyway, you most certainly will need Windows (preferably Access) to get anything from the file. Surely you have access to a PC somewhere?

Comment: I probably do mean action queries. And yes, you probably are right about needing a windows machine - thanks for the response.

Comment: You could get someone to dump the SQL from the queries. How big is the db in terms of filesize